# Aligning Textbox and checkboxes in asp.net MVC5 Form with Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I know similar questions have been asked in the past but I can't find one matching and providing a solution to my problem, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to build a form with one textbox and various checkboxes display below it. In front of the textbox and each checkbox, but I can't figure out why the textbox label is not aligned with the label from the checkboxes and the checkboxes are not aligned with the textbox.

Here's the code I have so far. Note that I'm using (bootstrap-lumen.css)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Staffs"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Staff Member</legend>
        <div class="form-vertical">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsAdmin, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <label>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsAdmin)
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CanDownloadCsv, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <label>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CanDownloadCsv)
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Here's what it look like when rendered:

[image]

I've tried removing all classes to see if it would help, but everything seems to be getting messed up where the label is display much lower than the checkbox and so on.

I'd like all my labels to be aligned with one another and my textbox and all checkboxes to be aligned with one another as well.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong and how can I resolve this?

Comment: How does you css for `class="checkbox"` vary from `class="form-group"`? And why have you wrapped the `CheckBoxFor()` inside a `<label>`? (the textbox is wrapped in `<div class="col-md-10">`)

Comment: Hi, I'm just following an online tutorial and I think this is how it was implemented. I've removed the label, and it has made very little difference. The checkboxes are slightly closer to one another. The class applied to the textbox, seems to extend it further by setting it to col-md-10. I'll try to find both classes and post them if that can help.

Comment: I suspect you just need to replace `<div class="checkbox">` with `<div class="form-group">` or `<div class="form-group checkbox">` and replace `<label>` with `<div class="col-md-10">` and use `@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsAdmin, new { @class = "form-control" })` to match the styles used by the textbox

Comment: @StephenMuecke you should put this as an answer! You were correct regarding the `<div class="mod-md-10">`. This was the problem all along. I was looking at something else but the second I removed that, all controls were aligned successfully.

Comment: That seems to what Bits_Please's answer is (except its missing the `new { @class = "form-control" }` in the `CheckBoxFor()` method)

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try this?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Staffs"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   <fieldset>
    <legend>Staff Member</legend>
    <div class="form-vertical">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group checkbox">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsAdmin, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">

                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsAdmin)

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group checkbox">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CanDownloadCsv, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">

                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.CanDownloadCsv)

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</fieldset>
}
```

Comment: I've tried what you suggested, but the layout is totally messed up in both Chrome & Edge.